# defining math concepts

Tags: math-mode, undefined

I would like to know how to fix:

```
Namely the study of arrows in~$\Cat_{/\cal{E}}$.
```

The error is

```
Undefined control sequence.

 < recently read > \Cat 

l.46 ... view. Namely the study of arrows in~$\Cat _{/\cal{E}}$.
```

I am using

```
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}

\usepackage{amssymb,url,xspace,smfthm}

\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
```

Comment: The error says it all ... `\Cat` isn't defined. What do you want it to do?

Comment: use a package to define object of the theory of categories (would be the ideal scenario), but the real thing is that I do not know how to define it.

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: page 122 https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0206203.pdf "des flèches dans une catègorie ~$\Cat _{/\cal{E}}$"

Comment: [Cat](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cat) stands for category of categories

Answer (score 6):

Couldn't resist.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\begin{document}
The theory of arrows from a topological point of view.
Namely the study of arrows in~$\Cat_{/\mathcal{E}}$.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with a cat]

A more realistic version with the output as in the paper:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\newcommand*{\Cat}{\mathbf{Cat}}
\begin{document}
The theory of arrows from a topological point of view.
Namely the study of arrows in~$\Cat_{/\mathcal{E}}$.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I prefer the first version.

Comment: Please, fix `\cal`

Comment: Thanks @egreg and @peter. The second example now uses package `calrsfs` so that `\mathcal` can remain.